# c# check if event is null

Tags: c#, events, null

I have this event in a webservice:

```
public event FindProductsByCharacteristicsCompletedEventHandler FindProductsByCharacteristicsCompleted
    {
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
        add
        {
            _findProductsByCharacteristicsCompleted += value;
        }
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
        remove
        {
            _findProductsByCharacteristicsCompleted -= value;
        }
    }
```

And im then checking if the event value is null with this later in the class:

```
private void OnFindProductsByCharacteristicsOperationCompleted(object arg)
    {
        var handler = _findProductsByCharacteristicsCompleted;
        if (handler == null)
            return;
        handler(this, new FindProductsByCharacteristicsCompletedEventArgs(completedEventArgs.Results, completedEventArgs.Error, completedEventArgs.Cancelled, completedEventArgs.UserState));
    }
```

Comment: Why do you feel you need to check if the event is null? Because you don't need to do this based on your code it can't be null.  Provide you subscribe to the event of course.

Comment: @Ramhound: If no one subscribed to the event it is `null`. Not checking for `null` is a pretty bad idea.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth - More then aware that. The Event and its handler is two entirely different things.  I also had a "provided" statement for a reason.

Comment: @PeteTheGreek - There is not such thing as `.NET Framework 2.5` please update your question so we know what your using exactly.

Comment: @Ramhound: That "provided" statement is useless, as you never know whether someone subscribed or not, unless you check for null.

Comment: This is a good article about event handling and race conditions.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/29/events-and-races.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your event implementation looks like it is an endless recursion. You are using the property itself in its implementation.
Change it to this:

```
private FindProductsByCharacteristicsCompletedEventHandler
            _findProductsByCharacteristicsCompleted;

public event FindProductsByCharacteristicsCompletedEventHandler
                 FindProductsByCharacteristicsCompleted 
{
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
    add
    {
        _findProductsByCharacteristicsCompleted += value;
    }
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
    remove
    {
        _findProductsByCharacteristicsCompleted -= value;
    }
}
```

And now, implement your method like this:

```
var handler = _findProductsByCharacteristicsCompleted;
if(handler == null)
    return;

handler(this, new FindProductsByCharacteristicsCompletedEventArgs(...));
```

This has the advantage that it is thread-safe.

Even if someone detached the last handler from the event after you checked for null but before you actually raised the event, you would not get an exception, because you are operating on the unchanged local variable.

Comment: hmm I still get the FindProductsByCharacteristicsCompleted' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -= error with this?

Comment: Can't get that to compile, what am I missing here?

Comment: @PeteTheGreek: I don't know. The error message would be helpful ;)

Comment: Still getting the "The event 'FindProductsByCharacteristicsCompleted' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -="

Comment: @PeteTheGreek: You should be using the latest version of the code from my answer.

Comment: Thanks, reloaded the browser and it compiled for some strange reason, danke!

Comment: @PeteTheGreek: Bitte. The source of your problems most likely was the recursive definition of the event.

Comment: It's thrown another issue, daniel when it tries to call another function from the handler, have updated my post...

Comment: @PeteTheGreek: You have to do a little bit of thinking yourself. Compare your original code with the code in my answer. You will notice that I ommitted the line that creates the `completeEventArgs` variable...

Comment: Yeah, realised I missed that the second I posted, going too fast! Thanks for your help.